# How to get proper result from web scraping (about flight information in Kayak)?

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
url = 'https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights/SEL-LON/2020-12-31?sort=bestflight_a'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
deptimes = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'depart-time base-time'})
deptimes
```

In Kayak, I have tried to get departure time information of flights from Seoul to London.
The result is `[]`, and I'm trying this format to other information but the results are same always.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into what you get back as a `response.content`, `kayak.co.uk` thinks (correctly) that you're a bot and sends this (among other stuff)

> If you are seeing this page, it means that KAYAK thinks you are a "bot," and the page you were trying to get to is only useful for humans.

However, a slight modification of the code tricks the server enough to return what you're looking for.

Try this:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights/SEL-LON/2020-12-31?sort=bestflight_a'
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

departure_times = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'depart-time base-time'})

for _time in departure_times:
    print(_time.text)
```

This outputs:

```
00:25
00:25
00:25
14:30
14:30
13:00
13:00
... and so on
```

Comment: @SuHyeon if you find the answer useful, could you please accept it?